# Why are my codes error today and fine yesterday?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarTest {

    /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //create a Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     *Creates a car! object from the Car class
     *with the passing of these arguments
     *year, make, model, price
     */
    Car car1 = new Car("2008", "Nissan", "Pathfinder", "10,000");

    //display toString using car1 object
    System.out.println(car1.toString());

    //user input for year
    System.out.println("Please list your automobile for sale: " +
        "\nPlease enter the year? ");
    //String newYear variable is created for CarTest class
    String newYear = input.nexLine();
    //set year in car class for Car1 object to String newYear
    car1.setYear(newYear);

    //user input for make
    System.out.println("Please enter the make? ");
    //String newMake variable is created for CarTest class

        String newMake = input.nextLine();
    //set make in car class for Car1 object to String newMake
    car1.setMake(newMake);

    //user input for model
    System.out.println("Please Enter the model?");
    //String newModel variable is created for CarTest class
    String newModel = input.nextLine();
    //set model in car class for Car1 object to String newModel
    car1.setModel(newModel);

    //user input for price
    System.out.println("How much would you sell your car for?");
    //String newPrice variable is created for CarTest class

    String newPrice = input.nextLine();

    //set price in car class for Car1 object to String newPrice
    car1.setPrice(newPrice);

    //displays the new info to the screen
    System.out.println(car1.toString());
    }
}
```

from

```
public class Car {

    //class variables are created
    private String year;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String price;

    //default constructor
    public Car() {
    }

    //constructor with arguments
    public Car(String year, String make, String model, String price) {
    this.year = year;
    this.model = model;
    this.make = make;
    this.price = price;
    }

    //get make of the vehicle
    public String getMake() {
    return make;
    }

    //set make for vehicle
    public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
    }

    //get model of the vehicle
    public String getModel(){
    return model;
    }

    //set model for vehicle
    public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
    }

    //get price of the vehicle
    public String getPrice() {
    return price;
    }

    //set price for vehicle
    public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
    }

    //get year of the vehicle 
    public String getYear() { 
    return year;
    }

    //set year for vehicle
    public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() {
    return "For Sale By Owner: " + year + " " + make + " " + model + 
            "\nSelling Price: $" + price + "\n ";
    }
}
```

It worked fine when i handed it last week for an assignment, but today, when i came to my computer for a new homework, I found red x's on my `car.java`, and `carTest.java`.

My eclipse is saying that : from `carTest.java` is full of errors and:
`error: main method not found in class homework.cartest. please define the main method
public static void main(String[] args)`

error is in the way I defined CAR1:
`Car car1 = new Car("2008", "Nissan", "Pathfinder", "10,000");`

and the ways i am getting the inputs

```
String newYear = input.nexLine();
String newMake = input.nextLine();
String newModel = input.nextLine();
String newPrice = input.nextLine();
```

with the `input.nextLine();` being underlined as an error in the code in eclipse.

also in the `Car.java`.  the method `String toSTring()` causes an error stating `"change toString() type to String type.`

it worked fine when I handed it and got a good grade for it, but today I noticed my codes to be errors, when all was okay yesterday?

Comment: Step 1: Read the error messages.

Comment: Please format your question in a more acceptable way.

Comment: provide the package of the class

Comment: Did you copy or move your project or files?

Comment: if i wrote the Car.java code itself without a test class, I still do not understand why the my method of toString() causes an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file listed under package/project Homework?

If not, reading your error-message correctly, you're trying to run something that doesn't exist.

At the same time, as said above, you could be experiencing filepath issues. Creating a new project and copy-pasting your code (refactored copy) is usually the quickest solution.

Comment: I created a new project under a new package, and copied and pasted the codes and it worked fine.  Using the "refactored copy" worked perfectly.  I wonder what happened in the last day on my computer to make it like that, when i did not use the eclipse program in the last couple days...works perfect now...

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to select me as answer so the rest knows this is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build the project. May be an anomaly with your Java build path

Answer (score 0):

Copied your project and runned it. Only thing that is wrong with it is:

```
String newYear = input.nexLine();
```

should be:

```
String newYear = input.nextLine();
```

For the rest, it works fine.

And in the `toString` method you should add an `@override` annotation

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "For Sale By Owner: " + year + " " + make + " " + model
            + "\nSelling Price: $" + price + "\n ";
}
```

Also make sure your project is called `CarTest`  and Source packages `package cartest`